# Is it possible to get information from this type of url: website.com/hello/richard

Tags: php, html, url

For example, if there is a url like `www.website.com/hello/richard`, would it be possible to echo hello and 100 separately onto my page.

eg:

**hello** how are you today **richard**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it would be. Try this:

```
$myURL = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$myTokens = explode('/', $myURL);
echo $myTokens[1] . "blah" . $myTokens[2];
```

This code gets the current URL into the **myURL** variable, then it calls a function called **explode** which turns it into an array based on the position of the '\' character. Then it echos out certain elements of that array. If you play around with output using echo you will soon see for yourself what is going on.

Comment: Sorry I Forgot to escape the backslash, try now :)

Comment: The two tokens are not echoing :( hahaha so close though!

Comment: you used the wrong slash for a URL (\ instead of /). The correct one doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: Yes I do now. Just read it up. Just wasn't sure how to get it I can now echo out the tokens anywhere to get the it! cheers buddy

Comment: sweet! remember to use print_r($myTokens) if you want to print out whole arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the data from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and then do whatever you like with it.

Comment: Could you expand on that? Not the pro php here just a newbie

Comment: That function gets the current URI, see this page: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: It isn't a function. It is a member of an array.

Comment: Hey buddy so yeh I echoed out my Url but I get /hello/richard What I am trying to do is get them both separately to echo them both separately

Comment: @user1616846 — http://php.net/explode — I suggest that you might want to try an introductory PHP tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Sure that's possible. You can get URL as a string using `$_SERVER['request_uri]`. Then you might want to use `explode` function to firm array of strings where delimiter is /. Then you may parse it. Or you can do this via .htaccess using rewrite rule